# The multi-part identifier "S.flag" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a two table one name is "user" and another name is "Prod".

My query is

```
update User_list_SQL set team=s.uteam, S.flag='Y' 
from User_list_SQL as U, SQlVal as S 
where U.name=S.uname
```

the error comes the following

[SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "S.flag" could not be bound.

How to write the query the above instance? please advice. Thanks

Comment: You can update one table at a time.

Comment: This is not possible. You can only update one table in one statement. You will have to split this out in to two statements.

Comment: Hello Friend how to update? but this is possible in MS-access 2010

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server is not Microsoft Access.

Comment: yes i know (Microsoft SQL Server is not Microsoft Access.).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update two tables at once. You will need to split it into 2 queries.

Follow below post..

[Update multiple tables in SQL Server using INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115759/update-multiple-tables-in-sql-server-using-inner-join)