# Why don't oracle support Updating multiple table in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sql-update

is following sql valid ?

```
UPDATE suppliers, contacts
SET suppliers.status = 'Active',
    contacts.note = 'Also Supplier'
WHERE suppliers.supplier_id = contacts.contact_id;
```

but oracle is not supporting.
why?

[How to update two tables in one statement in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: This is not valid sql.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php please refer this reference EXAMPLE - UPDATE MULTIPLE TABLES

Comment: That link is plain wrong. The statement is **not** valid (standard) SQL.

Comment: Absolutely, Link is surely not correct. You can't update multiple table same time.

Comment: copy content from that site: EXAMPLE - UPDATE MULTIPLE TABLES

Let's look at an UPDATE example that shows how to update multiple tables in an UPDATE statement. Please note that this syntax is not valid in Oracle).

Comment: Are you sure about that statement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115759/update-multiple-tables-in-sql-server-using-inner-join

Comment: Your query uses a highly non-standard extension of SQL that I believe is only supported by MySQL.  So, in a sense, Oracle does support it (the Oracle Corporation owns MySQL).

Comment: Did you read any of the answers to the SO posts you've linked?  Both of them clearly say `You can't update multiple tables in one statement`

Comment: I think it is a valid question since Oracle supports [Multitable Inserts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55089)

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the sql supplied is NOT valid.

As others have stated in the comments, the link you supplied is a question about if you can update multiple tables in a single statement in SQL Server.
The answer to that question is also **No**